# Pester with BeforeAll gives "Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Scriptblock'"

Tags: powershell, pester

I have added a new unit test file for Pester 5 to my Powershell repo in VS code.

When I try to run/debug it, I get a prompt in Terminal:

```
cmdlet BeforeAll at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Scriptblock:
```

If I enter a random string "hgj", I get the error:

```
[-] Discovery in C:\XXX.Tests.ps1 failed with:
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Scriptblock'. Cannot convert the "hgj" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". ---> System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationMetadataException: Cannot convert the "hgj" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". ---> System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the "hgj" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
```

This is the unit test file:

```
BeforeAll 
{
}

Describe 'Start-Package564' 
{
    It 'Runs Start-Package' 
    {
        
    }
}
```

If I comment out Before-All, everything works.

If I add some code in Before-All, I still get the prompt and the error.

Why does Before-All cause the Terminal to prompt for a scriptblock?

Comment: Move the opening `{` up on the same line as `BeforeAll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeforeAll` is a command, not a keyword (same for `Describe` and `It`).

For this reason, you need to supply the scriptblock literal *on the same line* so that PowerShell knows you meant to pass it as a parameter argument to `BeforeAll` - otherwise it just sees two separate statements: invocation of `BeforeAll` without any arguments, followed by a scriptblock literal.

To fix:

```
BeforeAll {
}

Describe 'Start-Package564' {
    It 'Runs Start-Package' {
        
    }
}
```